# SimpleJdbcCall Typing Issue and Ref Cursors

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a stored procedure from an Oracle DB. I am attempting to call to the database with a Spring Boot project in my DAO using SimpleJdbcCall (I create a simpleJdbcCallFactory in another file). Inside of Oracle SQL Developer, I am able to successfully call to the DB and get the desired result using the following commands:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
variable v_cur refcursor
call ABC.DATABASE_DATA.PROCEDURE_GET_DATA('', '', '1234', :v_cur)

// takes in PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3, out v_cur
```

I believe the ref cursor is what's causing issues for me, as I am unsure on how to properly handle it.

Other details to note:

- In Oracle SQL Developer, I can see that **PARAM1**, **PARAM2** & **PARAM3** are all of mode IN & data type VARCHAR2(200). **RETCUR** is of mode OUT & data type DATABASE_DATA.PRRETCUR.
- Spring Boot 3 & Java 17 are being used. The database is an Oracle SQL database.
- *I cannot change anything about the package or DB*. It is not my DB.

**ATTEMPT 1**: With SimpleJdbcCall (highly preferred)

```
// input = MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("PARAM1", param1).addValue("PARAM2", param2).addValue("PARAM3", param3);

public DBResponse retrieveData(SqlParameterSource input) {
    DBResponse dbResponse = new DBResponse();

    try {
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = simpleJdbcCallFactory.create(jdbcTemplate);
        simpleJdbcCall.withSchemaName("ABC")
            .withCatalogName("DATABASE_DATA")
            .withFunctionName("PROCEDURE_GET_DATA")
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .declareParameters(
                new SqlOutParameter("v_cur", OracleTypes.REF_CURSOR),
                new SqlParameter("PARAM1", Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter("PARAM2", Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter("PARAM3", Types.VARCHAR)
            }
        String out = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(String.class, input);
        dbResponse.setResult(out)
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // exception code ...
    }
```

Note that I have a service file that will parse the result stored in dbResponse. This results in the errors below:

```
"message":"Extracted SQL state class '65' from value '65000'"

...

"stacktrace":"org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call ABC.DATABASE_DATA.PROCEDURE_GET_DATA(?, ?, ?, ?)}]
...
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE_GET_DATA'
Statement ignored"...
```

Additionally, this is one of the logs that get printed out:

```
"message":"The following parameters are used for the call
{call ABC.DATABASE_DATA.PROCEDURE_GET_DATA(?, ?, ?, ?)} with {PARAM1=null, PARAM2=null, PARAM3=123}"
// please note that only one of params 1-3 is needed for the function
```

This tells me that maybe the ref cursor isn't involved? But I'm not sure on how to add it in if anyone could please assist!

Thank you all very much for your time & effort, and if more information is needed, I will gladly provide it!

Comment: Firstly, you have two `SqlParameter`s with name `PARAM2`. Is this a transcription error? It looks like you've anonymised your real code but not realised you've put the same parameter name in twice. Secondly, does it make a difference if you move the `SqlOutParameter` to the end of the list of parameters? That way the order of the parameters in the call to `.declareParameters()` matches the order of the parameters in your stored procedure.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct in that the PARAM2 issue was a transcription error. In the actual code they are separate-- I have edited it in the post. Trying to move the order of the parameters still results in the same error though.

Comment: OK, just taken a second look and spotted something else. As you are calling a stored procedure, not a stored function, does it make a difference if you replace `withFunctionName` with `withProcedureName`?

Comment: Does it help to sort parameters according to how they are declared in proc? Ie, the cursor should go last?